# Clojure and Compojure: Response Map is nil

Tags: clojure

I'm using compojure for a basic web app, I have this code in core.clj:

```
(defroutes routes
      (GET "/" [] (layout/application "Home" (contents/index)))
      (route/resources "/"))

(def application (handler/site routes))

(defn -main []
  (let [port (Integer/parseInt (or (System/getenv "PORT") "8090"))]
    (jetty/run-jetty application {:port port :join? false})))
```

When I access the 0.0.0.0:8090 everything is loading ok, but I keep seeing this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Response map is nil
    at ring.util.servlet$update_servlet_response.invokeStatic(servlet.clj:100)
    at ring.util.servlet$update_servlet_response.invoke(servlet.clj:91)
    at ring.util.servlet$update_servlet_response.invokeStatic(servlet.clj:95)
    at ring.util.servlet$update_servlet_response.invoke(servlet.clj:91)
    at ring.adapter.jetty$proxy_handler$fn__337.invoke(jetty.clj:27)
    at ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler$ff19274a.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I'd guess that `layout/application` is returning nil...

Answer (score 1):

@Svante is almost certainly correct.  An easy way to verify is to use the `spyx` function from [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo):

```
(ns demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core))

(defroutes routes
  (GET "/" [] (spyx (layout/application "Home" (contents/index))))
  (route/resources "/"))
```

which will print something like:

```
(layout/application "Home" (contents/index))) => nil
```

when run.  `spyx` ("spy explicit") prints the expression you give it, an arrow, and the expression value.  `spy`, `spyx`, `spy-pretty`, etc ***also return the value*** printed (unlike `println` which always returns `nil`) so you can insert a `spy` printout anywhere without disrupting the processing chain.  Thus, you don't need to write something like:

```
(defroutes routes
  (GET "/" [] (let [tmp-1 (layout/application "Home" (contents/index))]
                (println "layout/application result => " tmp-1)
                tmp-1)))
  (route/resources "/"))
```

in order to get a debug message printed.  In order to `spy` & friends, add this to the `:dependencies` in your `project.clj`:

```
[tupelo "0.9.138"]
```

---

### Update

Hmmmm.... Not sure what could be the problem.  I made a simple demo app from `lein new compojure demo-compojure` with the following:

```
(ns demo-compojure.handler
  (:use tupelo.core)
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]))

(defn index []
  (spy :index--result "Hello World"))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] (spyx (index)))
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))
```

and results:

```
~/expr/demo-compojure > lein ring server
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Started server on port 3000
:index--result => "Hello World"
(index) => "Hello World"
```

So that is working.  Also, `int?` is a basic Clojure function, so that is puzzling.  Perhaps make a clean demo project like the above and take it from there?

Comment: I added tupelo and got this error:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: int? in this context
 at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:221)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:7164)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:7108)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:7069)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6648)